# How to Split string before '@' in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic

I want to split an email of user before letter

> @

in Javascript especialy in angularJS. for example if its

> blabla@gla.com

it will turn into

> blabla

can someone give me a simple example to make it?
because i must split it from API and store it as localstorage,
some of example that i find its use limitTo but can we use it to cut it in specific way from `@` until end?

Comment: `String.split()` ?

Comment: yes it seems i can use split to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Try this `str.split()`

```
var email = "blabla@gla.com";
var userName = email.split('@');
console.log(userName[0]);
```

Or use `str.substring()`

```
var userName = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
console.log(userName);
```